# Apply a resample function to every column in dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, resampling

I have a 90 x 19 dataframe and I want to apply the resample2 (prospectr package) function to each one of the 90 columns.

I know how to use the apply function for each value on a dataframe, but in this case the function is applied to the whole column vector changing its length.

Any clue on this?

Please let me know if you require more input

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Got it, it was simpler than expected :)

```
    rspectra=matrix(NA,nrow(meanspectra2),ncol(meanspectra2))
for (i in 1:ncol(meanspectra2))

rspectra[,i]<-resample2(meanspectra2[,i], spectra, spectra, 5)
```

Where meanspectra2 is the 90x19 dataframe and rspectra is just an empty (NA) dataframe to be filled with the loop. Spectra and 5 are resample2 function inputs. Lookf for help("resample2") for more info.